# How to make simple XNA buttons?

Tags: c#, button, xna

I was wondering if anyone could show me a simple way of creating buttons in XNA.

Preferably a way to add a function when its clicked, and a way to add and remove them easily.

Comment: A button is no different than clicking on any sprite on a screen. You could create an event driven system, but that's a very windows form way of looking at it. Basically to do a button you draw a button like image on the screen and then detect if a click occurs within that region. That's about all there is to it. Is there a reason you want to go down an event driven route?

Comment: And how do you add a callback to your button?

Comment: @Kokodoko You could pass an action to your button, and invoke it on press.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using the [NeoForce Controls Library](http://neoforce.codeplex.com/) for GUI related problems - it has buttons, among the other useful GUI controls including popup windows, list views, combo boxes, and so on.

If you are writing a button class for the learning experience... well, try learning more about it yourself via Google before asking for help.

ADDENDUM

This is some code that I've written for buttons. Maybe it can serve as a starting point. I use it in my 2D game engine, so it has been debugged and tested.

> > 

```
/// <summary>
/// A control that changes appearance when it is hovered over and triggers some effect when it is clicked
/// </summary>
public class EnigmaButton
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The method signature for notification when a button is clicked
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">EnigmaButton that was clicked</param>
    public delegate void OnClickEvent(EnigmaButton sender);

    /// <summary>
    /// Types of textures used for Enigma Buttons
    /// </summary>
    public enum TextureType { Normal, Over, Press }

    #region Variables
protected IVisualExposer m_ui;
protected Rectangle m_bounds;
    IInputExposer m_input;
    bool m_over = false, m_press = false, m_wasPressed = false;

    Dictionary<TextureType, EnigmaResource<Texture2D>> m_textures;
    string m_text, m_name;
    EnigmaResource<SpriteFont> m_font;
    int m_minTextShadow, m_maxTextShadow;
    Color m_textTint;

    public event OnClickEvent OnClick;
    #endregion

    /// <summary>
    /// A control that changes appearance when it is hovered over and triggers some effect when it is clicked
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="ui">Graphical assets</param>
    /// <param name="input">Input exposer for mouse input and XBox controller input</param>
    /// <param name="reader">XMLReader for the definition of the controller</param>
    /// <param name="pos">Bounds of the controller</param>
    public EnigmaButton(IVisualExposer ui, IInputExposer input, XmlReader reader, Rectangle pos)
    {
    m_ui = ui;
    m_bounds = pos;
        m_textures = new Dictionary<TextureType, EnigmaResource<Texture2D>>();
        m_input = input;
        Enabled = true;

        #region Reading
        string name;
        bool started = false, insideText = false;

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader.MoveToContent() == XmlNodeType.Element)
            {
                name = reader.Name.ToLower();
                if (name == "button")
                {
                    if (started)
                        throw new Exception("Already started.");
                    started = true;

                    m_name = reader.GetAttribute("name") ?? string.Empty;
                }
                else if (!started)
                    throw new Exception("Not started");
                else if (name == "text")
                {
                    m_font = new EnigmaResource<SpriteFont>();
                    m_font.Filepath = reader.GetAttribute("font");

                    string minShadow = reader.GetAttribute("minShadow"), maxShadow = reader.GetAttribute("maxShadow");
                    m_minTextShadow = minShadow != null ? int.Parse(minShadow) : 0;
                    m_maxTextShadow = maxShadow != null ? int.Parse(maxShadow) : 2;

                    m_text = reader.GetAttribute("text") ?? string.Empty;
                    insideText = true;
                    m_textTint = Color.White;
                }
                else if (name == "bounds")
                {
                    insideText = false;
                    m_bounds = new Rectangle(int.Parse(reader.GetAttribute("x")), int.Parse(reader.GetAttribute("y")),
                        int.Parse(reader.GetAttribute("width")), int.Parse(reader.GetAttribute("height")));
                }
                else if (name == "texture")
                {
                    insideText = false;
                    TextureType texType = (TextureType)Enum.Parse(typeof(TextureType), reader.GetAttribute("type"));
                    if (m_textures.ContainsKey(texType))
                        throw new Exception("A texture of type '" + texType.ToString() + "' cannot  be registered twice");
                    EnigmaResource<Texture2D> res = new EnigmaResource<Texture2D>();
                    res.Filepath = reader.ReadString();
                    m_textures.Add(texType, res);
                }
                else if (name == "tint")
                {
                    if (!insideText)
                        throw new Exception("Tints can only be for text");

                    float a, r, g, b;
                    string[] split = reader.ReadString().Split(',');
                    if (split.Length != 4)
                        throw new Exception("Colors must be RGBA");
                    r = float.Parse(split[0].Trim());
                    g = float.Parse(split[1].Trim());
                    b = float.Parse(split[2].Trim());
                    a = float.Parse(split[3].Trim());

                    m_textTint = new Color(r, g, b, a);
                }
            }
        }
        #endregion

        if (!m_textures.ContainsKey(TextureType.Normal))
            throw new Exception("A button must have at least a '" + TextureType.Normal.ToString() + "' texture");
    }

    #region Methods
    public void Initialize()
    {
    }

    public void LoadContent()
    {
        EnigmaResource<Texture2D> res;
        for (int i = 0; i < m_textures.Count; i++)
        {
            res = m_textures[m_textures.ElementAt(i).Key];
            res.Resource = m_ui.Content.Load<Texture2D>(res.Filepath);
            m_textures[m_textures.ElementAt(i).Key] = res;
        }

        if (m_font.Filepath != null)
            m_font.Resource = m_ui.Content.Load<SpriteFont>(m_font.Filepath);
    }

    public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        m_wasPressed = m_press;
        m_over = m_bounds.Contains(m_input.MouseX, m_input.MouseY);
        m_press = m_over ? m_wasPressed ? m_input.IsMouseLeftPressed || m_input.IsButtonPressed(Buttons.A) : m_input.IsMouseLeftTriggered || m_input.IsButtonTriggered(Buttons.A) : false;
        if (!m_wasPressed && m_press && OnClick != null)
            OnClick(this);
    }

    public void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        Texture2D toDraw = m_textures[TextureType.Normal].Resource;
        if (Enabled)
        {
            if (m_press && m_textures.ContainsKey(TextureType.Press))
                toDraw = m_textures[TextureType.Press].Resource;
            else if (m_over && m_textures.ContainsKey(TextureType.Over))
                toDraw = m_textures[TextureType.Over].Resource;
        }
        m_ui.SpriteBatch.Draw(toDraw, m_bounds, Enabled ? Color.White : Color.Gray);

        if (m_font.Resource != null)
        {
            Vector2 pos = new Vector2(m_bounds.X, m_bounds.Y);
            Vector2 size = m_font.Resource.MeasureString(m_text);
            pos.X += (m_bounds.Width - size.X) / 2;
            pos.Y += (m_bounds.Height - size.Y) / 2;
            UIHelper.DrawShadowedString(m_ui, m_font.Resource, m_text, pos, m_textTint, m_minTextShadow, m_maxTextShadow);
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Properties
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the name of the button
    /// </summary>
    public string Name
    {
        get { return m_name; }
        set { m_name = value ?? m_name; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the text drawn in the button.
    /// WARNING: Will overflow if the text does not normally fit.
    /// </summary>
    public string Text
    {
        get { return m_text; }
        set { m_text = value ?? string.Empty; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the bounds of the button
    /// </summary>
    public Rectangle Bounds
    {
        get { return m_bounds; }
        set { m_bounds = value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Whether or not the control is enabled
    /// </summary>
public bool Enabled { get; set; }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Id seen NeoForce before, But it dosent seem like the kind of thing I would need here, Ive found some examples of Buttons online, but none have been what Id like. Ill probably just write my own class for it, But any info would be appreciated.

Comment: OK; I added some sample code to my answer. It's a bit simplified since I flattened the hierarchy it inherits from.

Comment: After more UI needs, I need to focus on gameplay not spending time writing ui classes, so I ended up using the neoforce controls library. Do you know how to use the DrawScene() function with it? It dosent seem to be working.